# Zend framework module, controller, action specific routes

Tags: zend-framework, routes, zend-route

In my zend framework application, I have routes and defaults like:

```
resources.router.routes.plain.defaults.module = "index"
resources.router.routes.plain.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.plain.defaults.action = "index"
```

I want to be able to change default routes for any module or controller or action
e.g.

Let's assume this module/controller/action structure:

```
content --- article --- read
                    --- write
        --- news    --- list
                    --- write
user    --- auth    --- signin
                    --- signout
        --- access  --- check
                    --- update
```

in this architecture,

for module=content I want 
controller=article to be default controller and 
action=read to be default action.
if controller=news is chosen then action=list becomes default action

for module= user I want
controller=auth to be default controller and action=signin to be default action.
if controller=access is chosen then action=check becomes default action.

So is it possible to do this in application.ini? And how for this example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Random Thoughts:

---

You could define a route for each module that points to those specific actions as defaults.

```
resources.router.routes.user.route = "user/:controller/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.user.defaults.module = "user"
resources.router.routes.user.defaults.controller = "auth"
resources.router.routes.user.defaults.action = "signin"
```

---

You could also define an `Module_IndexController::preDispatch()` or `User_AccessController::indexAction()` that uses `_forward` to send the request to the proper "default":

```
// delaing with the redirect in preDispatch
// will affect all requests to this controller
class User_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
  public function preDispatch() {
    // send to default location for User Module:
    $this->_forward('signin', 'auth')
  }
}

// dealing with the redirect in indexAction:
// will only affect requests that go to the "index" action
class User_AccessController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
  public function indexAction() {
    // send to default location for User Module:
    $this->_forward('check')
  }
}
```

From [Zend Framework Documentation - Controller Utility Methods](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.utilmethods)

> **`_forward($action, $controller = null, $module = null, array $params = null)`**: perform another action. If called in **`preDispatch()`**, the currently requested action will be skipped in favor of the new one. Otherwise, after the current action is processed, the action requested in **`_forward()`** will be executed.

Comment: I have thought about writing forwards in actions, but I am trying to code less in actions, do more in config files. I will try ini style after solving another problem with chaining my routes :)

Comment: And another question on chain routing I posted:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884716/zend-framework-route-chaining-in-application-ini
thanks..