# Zend Framework route chaining in application.ini

Tags: zend-framework, routes, chaining, zend-route, chain

I am setting language depending on the domain name (en for en.example.com, tr for tr.example.com):

```
resources.router.routes.plain.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.plain.route = "/:module/:controller/:action"
resources.router.routes.plain.defaults.language= "en"
resources.router.routes.plain.defaults.module = "content"
resources.router.routes.plain.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.plain.defaults.action = "index"

resources.router.routes.plain1.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.plain1.abstract = 1
resources.router.routes.plain1.route = "/:module/:controller/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.plain.defaults.module = "content"
resources.router.routes.plain.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.plain.defaults.action = "index"

resources.router.routes.dom0.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.dom0.abstract = 1
resources.router.routes.dom0.route = "en.example.com"
resources.router.routes.dom0.defaults.language= "en"
resources.router.routes.chn1.type = Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain
resources.router.routes.chn1.chain = "dom0, plain1"

resources.router.routes.dom1.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.dom1.abstract = 1
resources.router.routes.dom1.route = "tr.example.com"
resources.router.routes.dom1.defaults.language= "tr"
resources.router.routes.chn2.type = Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain
resources.router.routes.chn2.chain = "dom1, plain1"
```

the problem here is when I call url only with modulename and without specifying controller or action:
tr.example.com/content/
I get the language set to "en"

But when I call with modulename, controller and action:
tr.example.com/content/article/read
everything is fine

What do I do wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, notice that you have some naming issues, the defaults for `plain1` are defined on the `plain` route -- That is likely the problem, because you have no `defaults` defined for the `plain1` route, it requires the parameters to be there to match.

Comment: Sorry gnarf I didn't get what you meant "you have no defaults defined for the plain1 route". 
plain and plain1 have same defaults, the only difference between them is plain1 is abstract (to use in chain only).

In this config, according to last in first out rule the route queue should be:
1- chn2
2- chn1
3- plain
Am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah, looks like @gnarf nailed it. In the block where you (probably intend to) define the "plain1" route, it appears that you drop the trailing "1" in "plain1", leaving your with just "plain". Hence, your "plain1" route does not end up containing the module defaults you (probably) expect.

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified default module, controller and action for plain1.